# Aircrack перестал переключать wi-fi карту в режим монитора

Tags: linux, wifi, железо

*Aircrack* перестал переключать карту в решим монитора. Раньше все было нормально, а сейчас меняет *wlan0* на *wlan0mon* и все, режим остаётся тот же, как исправить?

Comment: Попробуй загрузиться с livecd типа Kali. Там всё работает?